# Using CSS to create a fixed Background image

Tags: css

I have been unable to create a background image (gray rectangle) that stays in a fixed position.  . When I scroll down the page, the image continues to scroll with the page instead of staying stationary as the images do.

This gray background image is being used only to create an outline for the left hand navigation.

```
body.ms-backgroundImage {
    background: url(../LandingPage/LAIPic1.png);
    background-size: 250px 455px;
    background-position: 8px 280px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image: How the background image is before the page is scrolled down]

[image: While the page is scrolled down, the gray background image also scrolls.]

Answer (score 0):

To have the menu sit on the side of the page like that you are going to want to use the css attribute `position: absolute;`.  Then to place it where you'd like use `top: 100px;` `left:10px;` using whatever values you would like.

Using this you can place it where you'd like on the page and it should stay where it is no matter when you are scrolling.  You can put this into a script editor on the page if you only want it there or in a file in your style library and reference to it in your master page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I was clear enough before, the background image I am referring to is just the gray rectangle behind the links. I tried your solution but the result was the same. Any other suggestions? Thanks